# Python Parsing Network

Tags: python, parsing, variables

I'm trying to parse an incoming packet, split some values and store them into their respective variable.

This illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
Incoming = "\x00\x31\x00\x62\x00\x6a\x00\x61\x00\x61\x00\x61\x00\x71\x00\x71"
Incoming+= "\x00\x71\x00\x61\x00\x71\x00\x6a\x00\x71\x00\x00\x00\x55\x00\x4e"
Incoming+= "\x00\x45\x00\x00\x00\x61\x61\x61\x00\x00\x00"

print Incoming
>>> 1bjaaaqqqaqjqUNEaaa
```

The strings I need to use are delimited by 3 null bytes "\x00\x00\x00", so it should look like this:

```
print Incoming
>>> 1bjaaaqqqaqjq UNE aaa
```

What I need to do is store "1bjaaaqqqaqjq" in var1, "UNE" in var2, "aaa" in var3.

I was thinking of something like :

```
Incoming = "\x00\x31\x00\x62\x00\x6a\x00\x61\x00\x61\x00\x61\x00\x71\x00\x71"
Incoming+= "\x00\x71\x00\x61\x00\x71\x00\x6a\x00\x71\x00\x00\x00\x55\x00\x4e"
Incoming+= "\x00\x45\x00\x00\x00\x61\x61\x61\x00\x00\x00"

pack = list(Incoming)
null = [i for i in range(len(pack)) if pack[i:i+3] == ['\x00','\x00','\x00']] 
for i in null:
   pack[i] = "\n"

print ''.join(pack)
>>>1bjaaaqqqaqjq
   UNE
   aaa
```

However my code can't assign these values to their respective var (var1,var2,var3,etc)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean:

```
>>> Incoming = "\x00\x31\x00\x62\x00\x6a\x00\x61\x00\x61\x00\x61\x00\x71\x00\x71"
>>> Incoming+= "\x00\x71\x00\x61\x00\x71\x00\x6a\x00\x71\x00\x00\x00\x55\x00\x4e"
>>> Incoming+= "\x00\x45\x00\x00\x00\x61\x61\x61\x00\x00\x00"
>>>
>>> var1, var2, var3 = [e.replace('\x00','') for e in Incoming.split('\x00\x00\x00')[:3]]
>>> print var1, var2, var3
1bjaaaqqqaqjq UNE aaa
```